# Update checked Gridview rows

Tags: vb.net, xtragrid

I had a problem with updating only the checked rows in `GridView` because I need to update one column cell value based on the ID value of the checked rows only.

I tried this code but it updates random rows, not the checked:

```
        Try
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To GridView1.SelectedRowsCount() - 1
                If (GridView1.GetSelectedRows()(I) >= 0) Then
                    Dim strID As String = GridView1.GetRowCellValue(I, "ID")
                    Dim strUpdate As String = "UPDATE records SET payment_order= @payment_order where ID = @ID"
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandText = strUpdate.ToString()
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_order", rfnd_id_lbl.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", strID)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            Next


        Catch ex As SqlException
            Dim errorMsg As String = "Error in Update"
            errorMsg += ex.Message
            Throw New Exception(errorMsg)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

Can anyone help me solving this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i])` to get selected record which should be used for updating parameters.

I hope it helps.

DX DOC: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetSelectedRows.method

Comment: Can you elaborate further on why this approach would help solve OP's original problem? Directing someone to the documentation is less effective than explaining the process behind why the solution would work. You do briefly explain what to use, but greater depth is needed.

Comment: I wrote it ==> use gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i])  instead of Dim strID As String = GridView1.GetRowCellValue(I, "ID")

Comment: This doesn't help elaborate on why your approach is more effective or why it would work. You may be seeing something that the OP, or that I myself, am missing, but without an explanation your answer is just a tidbit of code. Part of SO is explaining the *why* and not just the *how*. Given that the OP's question is from March, your answer runs the risk of being automatically cleaned up due to being vague.